# Issues with str.get_dummies() panda df loading from csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have  a CSV file whose content has experts and the list of skills he/she knows something like below

```
0   'Performance'   'Data'  
1   'Compiling' 'Algorithms'    
3   'Data'  'Algorithms'
```

I want to create a 0-1 matrix on the basis of which skills are held by which expert

Something like

```
ID    Performance Data Compiling Algorithms 
0              1    1      0        0
1              0    0      1        1
2              0    1      0        1
```

And then later store this matrix in a  dictionary like

```
(0,Performance): 1, (0:Data):1 , (0:Compiling):0, (0:Algorithms):0
(1,Performance): 0, (1:Data):0 , (1:Compiling):1, (1:Algorithms):1
(2,Performance): 0, (2:Data):1 , (2:Compiling):0, (2:Algorithms):1
```

My attempt so far has been

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('Expert_Skill_10KNodes.csv', sep=";")

df2= (df1.iloc[:,0].str.get_dummies(sep=','))

import itertools
Expert_Skill=({(x,y):df2[y][x] for x, y in list(itertools.product(df2.index, df2.columns))})
```

The code runs with no errors but does not produce desired output, it just skips most of the skills that the expert has

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain the desired output you can apply `pd.dummy_values()` to every column first, and subsequently, apply a column-wise `np.sum` as follows.

```
    id  skill1  skill2
1   0   'Performance'   'Data'
2   1   'Compiling' 'Algorithms'
3   3   'Data'  'Algorithms'
```

Given the pd.DataFrame above

```
 import pandas as pd
 dummy_dataframes = [pd.get_dummies(df[skill_col]) for skill_col in ['skill1', 'skill2']
 dummy_concat = pd.concat(dummy_dataframes).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

This will give you something closer, but you have multiple rows for one single id

```
    'Algorithms'    'Compiling' 'Data'  'Performance'
1   0   0   0   1
2   0   1   0   0
3   0   0   1   0
1   0   0   1   0
2   1   0   0   0
3   1   0   0   0
```

What you can do now is just apply column-wise `np.sum`.

```
import numpy as np
dummy_concat.reset_index().groupby('index').apply(np.sum, axis=0).drop('index',axis=1)
```

To get the desired output.

```
'Algorithms'    'Compiling' 'Data'  'Performance'

1   0   0   1   1
2   1   1   0   0
3   1   0   1   0
```